# How to get data and insert using id in php?

Tags: php, mysql, wamp

I make shopping site in php and I have one issue of product data.

```
First I make **product** datatabe below.

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `product` (                                    
       `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,                               
       `product_sales_id` int(11) NOT NULL,                                        
       `product_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,                                        
       `product_price` varchar(5000) NOT NULL,                                       
       `image_name` varchar(300) NOT NULL,                                               
       PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`)
    )


And Second table **product sales** below :

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `product_sales` (                                  
       `product_sales_id` int(11) NOT NULL,                                          
    )

Below page it admin site page when select product to insert in database and 
show in product page.

Add_Product.php : 

    <?php 
        include_once('include/connection.php');
        include_once('include/function.php');
    ?>

    <?php 
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            $product_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['product_name']);
            $product_price = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['product_price']);  
            $image_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, basename( $_FILES["product_image"]["name"]));

            $target_dir = "upload/";
            $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["product_image"]["name"]);
            $uploadOk = 1;
            $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            $filetype = $_FILES["product_image"]["type"];

            $image_upload = move_uploaded_file($_FILES["product_image"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);

            if($image_upload){
                mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO product(product_name,product_price,image_name) VALUES ('".$product_name."','".$product_price."','".$image_name."')");   
            }

        }
    ?>
```

I make on more page product sell page but i do not know how to make this
    Above show I make table product_sales and his id store in product table
    how to add product_sales in database and show in page using id through.

Comment: You need to give product_id in product_sales table but no need to give product_sales_id in products table as products never belong to any particular order forever.

Comment: Also how order can be directly placed from products to products_sales table? You need to make one temp table for shopping cart that will contain all products that user will add and when user will place order after reviewing the products then they will come in products_sales table after removing from temp table.

Comment: Also in temp table, you need to store products with session_ids first and when user login then need to add username or email in temp table as well.

Comment: You need to first learn how shopping cart site works only then you can do it correctly.

Comment: Thank for reply.

Comment: You are welcome. Let me know if anytime you face any issue.

Comment: Please mark the best answer as accepted if your issue has been resolved. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `product_sales_id` in `product_sales` table into primary key and add `product_id` field as a foreign key in `product_sales` table.

Once the product is sold, you can store the `product_id` in the `product_sales` table.

And you can fetch the sold product details from product table using `product_id` which is present in the `product_sales` table using join query.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on shopping site, then you are missing something very important.

You need to make one `temp` table for shopping cart that will contain all products that user will add and when user will place order after reviewing the products then they will come in products_sales table after removing from temp table.

Also you need to give `product_id` in `product_sales` table but no need to give `product_sales_id` in `products` table as products never belong to any particular order forever.